# How to post csrf token from android to spring?

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-security

I have Web API for Spring in Java . Now, I went to need GET and POST some Data in my android Apps. The Problem is CSRF token.First a I get csrf token in android apps. Then I post the csrf token form android apps in Web server. when I disable the csrf Security then I Post data web server from android.But when I enable the csrf Security then Post method is not working.

Now, how can I post a csrf token in web server from Android?

THANKS in advance ..

** ..The Post Method ..**
..................................

```
    public void sendPostCsrf(String mEmail, String mPassword, String mCsrf, String mCsrfHeader) {
    csrfApi.savePost(mEmail, mPassword, 1, mCsrf, mCsrfHeader)
            .enqueue(new Callback<PostModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PostModel> call, Response<PostModel> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //  showResponse(response.body().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Retrofit " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PostModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Retrofit " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });

}
```

...................................

The interface Post last URL code.
...................................

```
 @POST("/testingjsonpost")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<PostModel> savePostCsrf(@Field("email") String mEmail,
                         @Field("password") String mPassord,
                         @Field("userId") long userId,
                         @Field("_csrf")String csrf,
                         @Field("_csrf_header") String csrfHeader);
```

...................................

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: CSRF Token base authentication...